# Find a graph with a unique perfect matching and minimum degree $k$

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Given  $ k \gt 0 $ , how can i prove the existence of a simple graph $\mathbf G$ that satisfies the following:

$\bullet$ $\delta (G) \ge k.$ ($\delta$ := the the minimum degree of a vertex in G).

$\bullet$ $\mathbf G$ have a unique perfect matching.

i do know that $|G|, \delta(G) \ge 2k-1\Rightarrow \nu(G) \ge k $. ($\nu$ :=size of the maximum matching),
and i also know that a graph with a unique matching must has a cut edge.

but i cant figure out how to prove the statement above.

Comment: Hint: by induction. Suppose that you have a graph of minimum degree $k-1$ with a unique perfect matching, and then build an instance of minimum degree $k$ from it (or from several copies of it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can build it by induction on $\delta$.  For base cases, $G_1$ is $K_2$, a single edge between two vertices.  Here is an example $G_2$ with $\delta=2$.

[image]

Now assume we have a graph $G_k$ meeting the definition with $\delta=k$ for some positive integer $k$.  We shall create a graph $G_{k+1}$.  Start with a single edge, which will be our cut edge.  Then, for each end of the vertex, create a copy of $G$ and attach the end of the cut edge to every vertex of $G$.  That graph has $\delta=k+1$ and, by the induction hypothesis, has a unique matching.

In fact, $G_2$ is an example of using this algorithm from $G_1$.  Here is what $G_3$ would look like.
[image]

Comment: thanks. that's very helpful